# ListView con filas vacias

Tags: listview

Hola tengo una duda tengo un listView el cual lleno con una lista JsonArray, mi problemas es que al ser dinámica esa lista se rellena de una Base de datos lo cual puede venir con 2 elementos o puede venir con 100 elementos yo los guardo en un contenedor el cual por defecto me muestre 10 elementos osea dándole un tamaño fijo a esa lista aprox. 300dp el problema es que cuando la lista es menor de 10 osea solo trae dos elementos los pinta pero deja un espacio en blanco vació yo necesito una forma en el que pueda llenar el resto de la lista por ejemplo los otros 8 espacios que quedan y [introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zMyJE.png) que los ponga como filas vacías para simular una especie de libreta adjunto una imagen en la cual en ios si se puede quisiera replicar lo mismo y adjunto el código de mi adapter. gracias. es una fila que contiene cuatro elementos

codigo:
public class SimpleAdapterHistoric extends BaseAdapter {
    private static LayoutInflater inflater = null;
    Context context;
    private JSONArray jsonArray;

```
public SimpleAdapterHistoric(Context context, JSONArray jsonArray) {
    this.context = context;
    this.jsonArray = jsonArray;
    inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}

@Override
public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
    final View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.simple_adapter_historic, null);

    TextView one= (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.historic_element_first);
    TextView two = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.historic_element_second);
    TextView three = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.historic_element_third);
    TextView four = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.historic_element_fourth);
    try {
        one.setText((String) ((JSONObject) jsonArray.get(i)).get("firstValor"));
        two.setText((String) ((JSONObject) jsonArray.get(i)).get("secondValor"));
        three.setText((String) ((JSONObject) jsonArray.get(i)).get("threeValor"));
        four.setText((String) ((JSONObject) jsonArray.get(i)).get("lowValor"));

    } catch (Exception e) {
        one.setText("");
        two.setText("");
        three.setText("");
        four.setText("");
    }
    return rowView;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {

    return jsonArray.length();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int i) {
    try {
        return jsonArray.get(i);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return null;
    }
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int i) {

    return i;
}
```

}

Comment: Por qué no pruebas contando las filas de tu tabla y sí es menor a 10, le insertas filas en proporción a la diferencia del total.

Comment: que lenguaje de programación es?

Comment: el lenguage es java, e intentado hacer eso jorge luis pero no me funciona...